# springboot, how to valid @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

current code

```
    @Slf4j
    @RestController
    public class TestController {
        @Validated
        @PutMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        String test( @RequestBody @NotEmpty @Valid List<@NotBlank @Valid UUID> uuids) {
            return uuids.toString();
        }
    }
```

problem

```
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[]'

curl --location --request PUT 'localhost:8080' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[""]'
```

valid passes. But i don't want it

I want to validate the curl request in the sample above.
Is there any way to do it without dto?

Comment: What is the server response?

Comment: #Turing85.     
i just print request body, same with raw data

Comment: @ NotBlank is applied afaik only on Strings, you can remove it, and try to remove teh @ Valid before list, according to the example in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-list-controller is not needed.

Comment: @neoty You misunderstood my question. What is the actual response received by `curl`? I would expect an empty response body, or an empty list (depending on how Jackson is configured). Can you start the application in debug mode, set a breakpoint in method `test` and inspect the value of `uuids`?

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, I just understood your words. And I checked it. In conclusion, I solved the issue by declaring Validated in the answer below in the class.

Thank you for your hard work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of doing it

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@Validated
public class TestController {
    @PutMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    String test( @RequestBody @NotEmpty @Valid List<@NotNull @Valid UUID> 
     uuids) {
        return uuids.toString();
    }
}
```

**we have to annotate the beans, which shall be validated, with @Validated. Also for UUID @NotNull will suffice the requirement as No validator exists for this constraint for object UUID**

Validation Messages can also be customised by providing "message" param for @NotEmpty and @NotNull. like @NotEmpty(message = "cannot be empty")

If any of the validations fail, ConstraintViolationException is thrown. Exception handling can be done to customise this exception and throw 400 Bad Request.

Comment: The issue was resolved by declaring Validated in the class. Thank you for your help

Comment: @neoty [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Add a comment on the field

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
    @NotNull(message = "[id] cannot be empty")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "[name] cannot be blank")
    private String name;
    @NotBlank(message = "[email] cannot be blank")
    private String email;
    @NotBlank(message = "[birthday] cannot be blank")
    private Date birthday;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return JSONUtils.toJSONString(this);
    }
}
```

Use **@Validated** for validation

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/get")
    public String get(@Validated @RequestBody Person person) {
        return person.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as images.

Comment: The above method also works fine. Thank you for the reply.
The key was the Validated annotation.